# Making POST from Angular to PHP

Tags: php, angular, post

Well i try to post data from Angular to **PHP** file and print them ... and what i'm getting is NULL :(
I read all similar topics and still i have no clue whats going wrong or simply don't understand how this post works.

I Present short version to make things more clear.
I have file: 
**day.component.ts** with code:

```
query = '{"name":"ZZZ"}';
getResources() {
        return this.http.post('/api/db.php', this.query)
        .subscribe(
            (data) => {
                console.log('Got some data', data);
            }
        );
      }
```

As you can see i try to POST preformated JSON object with variable **query**.
I'm posting to **db.php** file which looks like:

```
<?php
    $json = file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
    $obj = json_decode($json, true);
    echo $obj["name"];
    var_dump($obj);
 ?>
```

Echo giving me nothing and var_dumb NULL.
Additionally i have error in **console**:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token Z in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse...
>
> Text: "ZZZarray(1) {↵  ["name"]=>↵  string(3) "ZZZ"↵}↵"

I'm struggling with this like 4 or 5 days ... 14 hours each day ... i'm almost DONE :X

Comment: Try sending data as object itself instead of converting it to an string .`query = {"name":"ZZZ"};`

Comment: Not entirely sure why your `$obj` is null but your unexpected token error in the console is because you're not outputting JSON from php. Try changing your `query` in Angular to an object and letting `http` take care of the serialisation, eg; `let query = { name: "ZZZ" }; this.http.post(query)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holly smoke guys prepare yourself guys because you never heard something stupid like this and you gonna laugh ...

My my POST code in Angular turned out to be perfectly fine same as php code.

I just tried to see the result of POST by going directly to my localhost/api/db.php file which was generating another request, in this situation GET request.

So my async POST data was wiped before i was able too basically see them.

5 days (14 hours of each) wasted ... oh God i need pills...

Sometimes you have to take HARD path to learn something.

Answer (score 0):

```
query = '{"name":"ZZZ"}';
    httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':  'application/json'
        })
      };
      getResources() {
        return this.http.post('/api/db.php', JSON.stringify(this.query), this.httpOptions)
        .subscribe(
            (data) => {
                console.log('Got some data', data);
            }
        );
      }
```

Comment: This is the Angular 4 and earlier way, but in Angular 5 introduced the HttpClient library and headers are added differently.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code again, it looks like you are creating `this.query` as a string:

```
query = '{"name":"ZZZ"}';
```

But, you probably want to create it as an object, like this:

```
query = {name:"ZZZ"};
```

I am not sure how the PHP json_decode() function works when given a string as an input, but I doubt it returns an object that allows you to access value properties off of.

You'll still need to set the headers below, though.

---

Original Answer:

As stated in other answers, you probably need to add a header that says your Content-Type is `application/json`.

When using the [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) library, introduced in Angular 5 you do it this way:

```
let options : Object;
let optionHeaders : HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
options = {headers:optionHeaders};
this.http.post('/api/db.php', this.query,options);
```

If you are using the [Http library](https://angular.io/api/http/Http) for Angular 4 or earlier, this is the way to do it:

```
let optionHeaders : Headers = new Headers();
optionHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
let options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({headers:optionHeaders});
this.http.post('/api/db.php', this.query,options);
```

Comment: `httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':  'application/json'
        })
      };


return this.http.post('/api/db.php', JSON.stringify(this.query), this.httpOptions) `
i did like in angular.io guide still nothing

Comment: well i think its a configuration related problem... still no result

Comment: I looked at your code again.  Are you intending to send a string; because you're creating `this.query` as a string instead of an object. I suggest sniffing your request with something like the chrome debug tools to see what is actually being sent as the request body.

Comment: In Request Payload in Chrome Tools i have
{"name":"ZZZ"}

Comment: i have one question more my php files should be located in in api folder on localhost:4200(Angular's server) or on localhost:80 (XAMPP PHP Server) ?

Comment: Your PHP Files should be on the PHP Server.

Comment: so as i expected... i found that i have outdated imports .... so changed from HttpClientModule to HttpModule and HttpClient to Http ... i'm not getting erros in console anymore but i still have empty POST ... so i think its configuration related problem ... what is funny on my XAMPP i'm getting empty post ... and when i tried CLI PHP server instead i was getting 505 no response ... LOL... i must definitely try POST on Firebase to see if it works but i'm nearly sure this approach gonna work ...

Comment: HttpClientModule is the latest HTTP Library introduced in Angular 5; it sounds like you downgrade to deprecated code. It is not obvious from your previous comment about request payloads whether you're actually seeing a string value or JSON value in chrome dev tools.

Comment: well it not possible that i downgraded because i saw those imports in brand new course of angular 6 :)
well i tried with both payloads:
"Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
with JSON string ex. data = '{"name": "John"}';

Comment: 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' with format data = 'name=John'

In both cases after var_dumping post data i got empty string

Comment: @zby Review the Angular doc link I provided in my answer: https://angular.io/api/http/Http .  Note it says  "Deprecation notes" also the current Angular docs point you to using HttpClientModule https://angular.io/guide/http .  It looks like someone missed that when updating the course you're using for Angular 6.